# Chamar uma page em outra asp.net-core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Bom dia, eu tenho uma pagina edit de Horários, que funciona perfeitamente, porém nesta pagina edit, eu preciso chamar a pagina Horario Item Index,
Estou tentando desta forma na pagina EDIT :

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10" id="replacetarget">
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("HorarioItem/Index", new { id = Model.Horarios.Id});
    </div>
</div>
```

Porém ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

> InvalidOperationException: A view component named 'HorarioItem/Index' could not be found. A view component must be a public non-abstract class, not contain any generic parameters, and either be decorated with 'ViewComponentAttribute' or have a class name ending with the 'ViewComponent' suffix. A view component must not be decorated with 'NonViewComponentAttribute'.

Como posso proceder ? Obrigado.

Comment: ela é uma partial view @mariana?

Comment: Estou aprendendo a linguagem agora e ainda estou apanhando muito, eu criei as pages com razors crud, e foi criada a pagina index, de horario item, que é a que eu preciso chamar.

Comment: Você precisa procurar sobre Partial View em AspNet esse é o caminho, fazer um ViewComponent nesse caso talvez não seja o ideal...

Comment: Você tem algum material que possa me ajudar ? Eu teria que criar outra pagina para partial View ?

Comment: Por exemplo: https://desenvolvimentoaberto.org/2015/06/04/asp-net-partial-views-razor-mvc-c/ e https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-2.0 essa segunda é a documentação oficial

Comment: No meu visual eu não tenho essas opções o projeto é desenvolvido em .NET Core 2.0 Utilizo Page Razor

Comment: Tem sim Mariana ... é do mesmo jeito

Comment: Ele me da a opção somente de criar uma PageRazor, ele não me deixa criar uma VIEW, que estranho. Como sou nova nesta especialidade, não sei se é devido core ou não.